# Difference between various CSS declarations

Tags: css

What is the difference between following css style descriptors?

```
    1>.foo .bar ???    
    {
      font-size:50%;
      ...
    }

    2>.foo.bar ???    
    {
      font-size:50%;
      ...
    }

    3>.foo,.bar ???    
    {
      font-size:50%;
      ...
    }
```

From what I have already found::

1> is AND operation that means elements that have both of the css classes, will obey this rule.

2> **No Idea** if this is different from 1.

3>is OR operation , elements that have either of the css classes.

Please help for clarification.

Comment: 1> is any descendant .bar of .foo    
2> is AND   
3> is OR

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Combinators_and_multiple_selectors

Comment: `.foo .bar` will affect nested span `<span class="foo"><span class="bar"></span></span>`  | `.foo.bar` will affect element with both class `<span class="foo bar"></span>` | `.foo, .bar` will affect both span elements  `<span class="foo"></span><span class="bar"></span>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **.foo .bar** - Selects all `.bar` elements inside `.foo` elements
2. **.foo.bar** - (AND) Selects elements with both classes
3. **.foo,.bar** - (OR) Selects all `.foo` elements and all `.bar`
   elements